# Can I use wired Xbox One controller

Tags: xbox-360

Can I use wired Xbox One controller? Googling only gave me Xbox 360 controller, and I don't think that the new Xbox One Controller can be mapped as old 360 one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My brother just bought a xbox one controller today and it does not work.

He tried the standard xpad driver as well as the xboxdrv but they apparently do not even recognize the press of a button :(

It's a sad thing to say but no you may not use a wired or wireless Xbox one(360 works absolutely fine) controller with ubuntu RIGHT NOW:

Looking around I was able to find this commit to the Linux kernel xpad driver

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/1a48ff81b3912be5fadae3fafde6c2f632246a4c

That means the work is already done and we have to wait for ubuntu to reach the kernel version that includes this controbution.

It was committed 7 days ago, that means it will probably be included in kernel version 3.18, but I'm absolutely not an expert so my prediction might be worth nothing.

If we are lucky xboxdrv(alternative to the  standard driver) will add support soon.

Comment: Looks like my patch should hit kernel 3.17 given the tags on the commit, but I don't know if/when that will hit Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: UPDATE:

Xbox One Controller support is defenetly in 3.17 as you can read here:

Linux Kernel 3.17 Is Out With Plenty of New Features
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/10/linux-kernel-3-17-whats-new-improved

The kernel version is not yet included with Ubuntu 14.10(the artikel on omg ubuntu covers that) but 14.10 is still in testing so I guess we can expect 3.17 to be included.

Answer (score 2):

I've compiled and made debian packages for "3.16.0-rc6" kernel with the xpad xbone controller support. Havent uploaded the packages yet though. Seems to work fine with epsxe.

```
Linux wepu 3.16.0-rc6 #2 SMP Mon Sep 22 21:16:48 BST 2014 i686 GNU/Linux

w*****h@wepu:~/Downloads/deb$ ls -l
total 373892
-rw-r--r-- 1 w*****h w*****h    966206 Sep 22 21:32 linux-firmware-image-3.16.0-rc6_3.16.0-rc6-2_i386.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 w*****h w*****h   6536604 Sep 22 21:33 linux-headers-3.16.0-rc6_3.16.0-rc6-2_i386.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 w*****h w*****h 342097294 Sep 22 22:06 linux-image-3.16.0-rc6_3.16.0-rc6-2_i386.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 w*****h w*****h  32491312 Sep 22 22:10 linux-image-3.16.0-rc6-dbg_3.16.0-rc6-2_i386.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 w*****h w*****h    765926 Sep 22 21:33 linux-libc-dev_3.16.0-rc6-2_i386.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

hello there have you check

gamepadtool download it here
click [here](https://www.generalarcade.com/gamepadtool/linux/)

and xpadneo here
click [here](https://github.com/atar-axis/xpadneo)

and install joystick via terminal

```
$sudo apt-get install joystick -y
```

but I got problems with wine it doesn't recognize my controller
but I gues I'm gonna needs some workaround

Comment: If this answer doesn't work, why are you posting it as a solution?

Comment: it does works but not in wine. wine is a compatibility layer that calls dynamic links library so if my driver is setup correctly but in wine the game don't recognize it. I've make my controller works in wine so I think this is a solution just need a little bit of tinkering